# Android SQLite Strange Error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Has anyone ever encountered this error before in these circumstances?

Couldn't read row 1, col 8, from CursorWindow.

I know this means that it's trying to read data from column 8, but the thing is I only have 7 columns and I am never trying to assign data from an 8th column obviously.

The issue I have is whenever I clear the data and start again, it works fine, then all of a sudden it starts throwing errors.

This is my table:

```
public String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE BreakTests ( " +
        "Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "Answered_Question_Set_ID INTEGER, " +
        "PassValue INTEGER, " +
        "Value1 INTEGER, " +
        "Value2 INTEGER, " +
        "Value3 INTEGER, " +
        "Value4 INTEGER, " +
        "Value5 INTEGER)";
```

These are my columns:

```
public final String KEY_ID = "Id";
public final String KEY_ANSWERED_QUESTION_SET_ID = "Answered_Question_Set_ID";
public final String KEY_PASS_VALUE = "PassValue";
public final String KEY_VALUE_1 = "Value1";
public final String KEY_VALUE_2 = "Value2";
public final String KEY_VALUE_3 = "Value3";
public final String KEY_VALUE_4 = "Value4";
public final String KEY_VALUE_5 = "Value5";

public final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID, KEY_ANSWERED_QUESTION_SET_ID, KEY_PASS_VALUE, KEY_VALUE_1, KEY_VALUE_2, KEY_VALUE_3, KEY_VALUE_4, KEY_VALUE_5};
```

This is my query:

```
 public ArrayList<BreakTest> GetForSync() {
    ArrayList<BreakTest> tests = new ArrayList<BreakTest>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT Id, Answered_Question_Set_ID, PassValue, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5 FROM BreakTests";
    Cursor cursor = Shared.db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {  });
    BreakTest breakTest;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            breakTest = new BreakTest();
            breakTest.Id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            breakTest.Answered_Question_Set_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWERED_QUESTION_SET_ID));
            breakTest.PassValue = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASS_VALUE));
            breakTest.Value1 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE_1));
            breakTest.Value2 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE_2));
            breakTest.Value3 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE_3));
            breakTest.Value4 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE_4));
            breakTest.Value5 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE_5));

            tests.add(breakTest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return tests;
}
```

I've worked with Android Studio and SQLite for a while now and I've never encountered this issue.

Any comments/feedback would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Could we have a copy of the stacktrace?

Comment: You existing table can have only 7 columns, You may added the new coumnrecently, Try to alter the table or clear your app data and then try again

Comment: Josh: Whenever I try to get the full stack trace my app crashes, all I can give is the exception message. MathaN: I have already cleared the data before and it works fine for a while then all of a sudden starts throwing errors.

Comment: **but the thing is I only have 7 columns** no, you have 8! `1-Id, 2-Answered_Question_Set_ID, 3-PassValue , 4-Value1, 5-Value2, 6-Value3, 7-Value4, 8-Value5  ` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all comments the issue was with this line of code;

```
breakTest.Id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
```

Changed to

```
breakTest.Id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you providing `new String[] {}` when you don't need to pass arguments?

Try this

```
Cursor cursor = Shared.db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, changed as suggested but made no difference.

Comment: Refer to @Grisgram answer, I think he's right. You have 8 columns.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can count, your table **has** 8 columns, not 7.
Id, question, pass and 5 values.
So a message "can't read from column 8" is very valid if it is, for instance simply NULL and you try a `.getInt` . `Use cursor.isNull(columnIndex)` to make sure, there is valid data inside, like

```
if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE_1))) breakTest.value1=cursor.getInt(...)
```

None of your columns is defined as NOT NULL, so you need to check in code.

Comment: If I am right here (as others already suggested too) you may say thanks by accepting this as the answer. thank you.

Comment: Column 8 is the ninth column. And this error message cannot happen for NULL values.

Comment: anyway, a null check is not a bad idea against a table that has nullable columns.